# Why does my variable don't "remember" the changes in the if-Statement?

Tags: loops, if-statement, variables

I got a problem with my code: My program is going to draw a few specific rectangles. Therefore I use a loop to calculate repetitive the size of my new rectangles.

```
    int c = readInt("Counter: ");
    double width1 = readDouble("Width: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= c; i++) {

        double height1;
        double lastwidth;
        double lastheight;
        double topleftx;
        double toplefty;


        if ((i == 1) && (i != 0)) {
            topleftx = 0;
            toplefty = 0;
            height1 = width1 / 1.618;
            GRect rect = new GRect(topleftx, toplefty, width1, height1);
            add(rect);
            lastwidth = width1;
            lastheight = height1;
        }
        ;

        if ((i == 2) || ((i - 2) % 4 == 0) && (i != 0)) {
            height1 = lastheight;
            width1 = height1 / 1.618;
            toplefty = toplefty;
            topleftx = topleftx + lastwidth - width1;
            GRect rect = new GRect(topleftx, toplefty, width1, height1);
            add(rect);
            lastwidth = width1;
            lastheight = height1;
        }
    }
```

But I get some error messages like that one:
*The local variable lastheight may not have been initialized.* 
in the line: `height1 = lastheight;` of the second loop. 
But I have already initialized my variable in the first loop. So it's like my variable forgot the value I gave to it in the first loop...?!

But why? And how can i fix this?

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to give them default value first:

```
double height1 = 0.0;
double lastwidth= 0.0;
double lastheight=0.0;
double topleftx=0.0;
double toplefty=0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the height1 variable on the time of declaration with default values.

because compiler checks every situation like what happens if first if statement never runs, in that case the height1 variable will be un initialized...

So, in these type of cases always initialize the variables with some default or dummy value. EG.

```
double height1 = 0.0;
```

Comment: Always Wellcome, Please up-vote the answer to help...! :)